# Write a function that only accepts literal `0` or literal `1` as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, constexpr, literals

Sometimes for algebraic types it is convenient to have a constructor that takes a literal value `0` to denote the neutral element, or `1` to denote the multiplicative identity element, even if the underlying type is not an integer.

The problem is that it is not obvious how to convince the compiler only to accept, `0` or `1` without accepting any *other* integer.

Is there a way to do this in C++14 or beyond, for example combining literals, constexpr or static_assert?

Let me illustrate with a free function (although the idea is to use the technique for a constructor that take a single argument. Contructors cannot take template parameters either).

A function that accepts zero only could be written in this way:

```
constexpr void f_zero(int zero){assert(zero==0); ...}
```

The problem is that, this could only fail at runtime. I could write `f_zero(2)` or even `f_zero(2.2)` and the program will still compile.

The second case is easy to remove, by using `enable_if` for example

```
template<class Int, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Int, int>{}> >
constexpr void g_zero(Int zero){assert(zero==0);}
```

This still has the problem that I can pass any integer (and it only fails in debug mode).

In C++ pre 11 one had the ability to do this trick to only accept a literal zero.

```
struct zero_tag_{}; 
using zero_t = zero_tag_***;
constexpr void h_zero(zero_t zero){assert(zero==nullptr);}
```

This actually allowed one to be 99% there, except for very ugly error messages.
Because, basically (modulo Maquevelian use), the only argument accepted would be `h_zero(0)`.

This is situation of affairs is illustrated here https://godbolt.org/z/wSD9ri .
I saw this technique being used in the Boost.Units library.

1) **Can one do better now using new features of C++?**

The reason I ask is because with the literal `1` the above technique fails completely.

2) **Is there an equivalent trick that can be applied to the literal `1` case?** (ideally as a separate function).

I could imagine that one can invent a non-standard long long  literal `_c` that creates an instance of `std::integral_constant<int, 0>` or `std::integral_constant<int, 1>` and then make the function take these types. However the resulting syntax will be worst for the `0` case. Perhaps there is something simpler.

```
f(0_c);
f(1_c);
```

---

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that since `f(0)` and `f(1)` are potentially completely separate functions then ideally they should call different functions (or overloads).

Comment: You mean like [`std::static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)? Not sure why you're using `assert` iny our example when `static_assert` is compile-time.

Comment: There's another problem with [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert): If the `NDEBUG` macro is defined (which is not unusual with release builds) then `assert` does nothing.

Comment: @tadman Because the argument is still interpreted as possibly runtime. If you try using `static_assert` instead of `assert` you get "error: non-constant condition for static assertion, 'zero' is not a constant expression". If one uses `if constexpr` one gets the same error. Try here: https://godbolt.org/z/pNRRcg

Comment: `enum LimitedInt : int { Zero, One };`

Comment: @Eljay yeah, and make it strongly-typed to prevent unintended int casts

Comment: And why does it have to be a literal zero or one? What problem is that supposed to solve, instead of using plain `bool`? Why does it have to be literals? Why can't you pass variables? This smells too much of an XY problem really.

Comment: @Eljay, yeah, but I couldn't use the `f(0)` syntax then, and ideally would like to have different functions for "0" and "1" which is something I should have mentioned. In any case this inspired me to do this which is a notch closer: Use a syntax `k(_0)` and `k(_1)` (no worst than literal `1_c`). See line 20 in https://godbolt.org/z/r4zvp5

Comment: By the way, if your compiler is recent enough perhaps the C++20 [`consteval` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) is what you need?

Comment: "zero or one" because "0" and "1" are symbols in math that represent generic elements given additive or multiplicative properties of the set (this is the XY problem). That is pretty unique of these two symbols. The bool solution is no better than the first solution in my question because it accepts values like `2` (and worst it cannot be checked afterwards). Also ideally I would like to still have separate functions for `0` and `1`. `consteval` seems to be the feature I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++20 you can use the `consteval` keyword to force compile time evaluation.  With that you could create a struct, which has a `consteval` constructor and use that as an argument to a function. Like this:

```
struct S
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    S() = delete;

    consteval S(int _x)
        : x(_x)
    {
        if (x != 0 && x != 1)
        {
            // this will trigger a compile error,
            // because the allocation is never deleted
            // static_assert(_x == 0 || _x == 1); didn't work...
            new int{0};
        }
    }

    int get_x() const noexcept
    {
        return x;
    }
};

void func(S s)
{
    // use s.get_x() to decide control flow
}

int main()
{
    func(0);  // this works
    func(1);  // this also works
    func(2);  // this is a compile error
}
```

Here's a [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/T2XcYU) as well.

Edit:
Apperently `clang 10` does not give an error as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/FnDpuZ), but `clang (trunk)` on godbolt does.

Comment: There is a very important limitation in your answer, I think the code inside the `consteval` constructor has to be evaluable at compile time which prevents allocation. So if the neutral or the identity element need to allocate for example it won't be able to.

Comment: @alfC I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  `void func(S s)` is equivalent to having `void func(int x)` where `x` is limited to `0` or `1`, and has to be provided at compile time.  The allocation is only there in the constructor to trigger an error, it could be anything else that causes and error, like `assert(false)` or `exit(1)` (note that `assert(false)` won't work for release builds).  Also in C++20 we have `constexpr new`.

Comment: you are right I didn't interpret the code right. S is just a wrapper, not the actual class one want to construct from 0, or 1. Here it is a more simplified version of the answer, I would still want to get rid of the conditional in line 12: https://godbolt.org/z/qtHERP

Comment: Currently in C++ I don't know of any way you could do that. To do that you'd need `consteval`/`constexpr` function arguments, which may be coming in future versions of C++. Also your simplified example has a flaw, where you could construct a `zeroone_t` and then change the value of `n_`. To fix this you could make it a private member, like in my original answer or make `n_` be a `const int`.

Comment: Yes, I simplified the solution to show it in a context more oriented to constructors. This is my failed step forward https://godbolt.org/z/Qzrw_c . It produced an ambiguous call before getting to the consteval part.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately since arguments of `consteval` functions cannot be used in constant expressions, you can't use SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is as far as one can get for now. I am trying to backport it to c++17. Is there is a substitute (workaround) for `consteval` for pre c++20? (without  templates themselves)

Comment: Not that I know of.  If you want to use this in C++17 I think you're best off using literal operators and calling functions like `func(0_x)` or an `enum`.

Answer (score 5):

You can get this by passing the 0 or 1 as a template argument like so:

```cpp
template <int value, typename = std::enable_if_t<value == 0 | value == 1>>
void f() {
    // Do something with value
}
```

The function would then be called like: `f<0>()`. I don't believe the same thing can be done for constructors (because you can't explicitly set template parameters for constructors), but you could make the constructor(s) private and have static wrapper functions which can be given template parameters perform the check:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    A(int value) { ... }

public:
    template <int value, typename = std::enable_if_t<value == 0 || value == 1>>
    static A make_A() {
        return A(value);
    }
};
```

Objects of type `A` would be created with `A::make_A<0>()`.

Comment: Your answer is conceptually right. As you mention, the only reason I cannot use is that I cannot do auto `z = T{0}` with it. Also I would like to have separate functions for `0` and `1` which is possible from your answer by specializing `f<0>()` and `f<1>()` or `make_A<0>()` and `make_A<1>()`. I will vote it because it can help in other contexts (outside constructors).

Answer (score 4):

Well... you have tagged C++17, so you can use `if constexpr`.

So you can define a literal type when `0_x` is a `std::integral_constant<int, 0>` value, when `1_x` is a `std::integral_constant<int, 1>` and when `2_x` (and other values) gives a compilation error.

By example

```
template <char ... Chs>
auto operator "" _x()
 {
   using t0 = std::integer_sequence<char, '0'>;
   using t1 = std::integer_sequence<char, '1'>;
   using tx = std::integer_sequence<char, Chs...>;

   if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<t0, tx> )
      return std::integral_constant<int, 0>{};
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<t1, tx> )
      return std::integral_constant<int, 1>{};
 }

int main ()
 {
   auto x0 = 0_x;
   auto x1 = 1_x;
   //auto x2 = 2_x; // compilation error

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x0),
                                 std::integral_constant<int, 0>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x1),
                                 std::integral_constant<int, 1>> );
 }
```

Now your `f()` function can be

```
template <int X, std::enable_if_t<(X == 0) || (X == 1), bool> = true>
void f (std::integral_constant<int, X> const &)
 {
   // do something with X
 }
```

and you can call it as follows

```
f(0_x);
f(1_x);
```

Comment: Very complete solution. Yes, I tagged c++17 to allow solutions in newer versions of C++. `if constexpr` is not fundamental in your solution BTW.  One still would need to call the function (or constructor) as `f(0_x)` (or `f(1_x)`). Is there a way to be able to pass the literal "into" f? so that `f(0)` and `f(1)` also work?

Comment: @alfC - for `f(0_x)` and `f(1_x)` is simple (improved answer); for `f(0)` and `f(1)`... I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If we had functions that could take literals themselves (and as arguments) this could be solved.
`template <char ... Chs> auto f( "" Chs...)` (or some syntax like this).

Comment: @alfC - no, `if constexpr` isn't fundamental but avoid the need of a couple of functions, SFINAE enabled/disabled.

Comment: @alfC - For literals taken by functions... maybe through a C-style macro. But I consider C-style macros distilled evil.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a modern solution, but adding on to Zach Peltzer's solution, you can keep your syntax if you use macros...

```
template <int value, typename = std::enable_if_t<value == 0 | value == 1>>
constexpr int f_impl() {
    // Do something with value
    return 1;
}


#define f(x) f_impl<x>()

int main() {
    f(0); //ok
    f(1); //ok
    f(2); //compile time error
}
```

Though, with the constructor problem you could just make the class templated instead of trying to have a templated constructor

```
template<int value, typename = std::enable_if_t<value == 0 | value == 1>>
class A {
public:
    A() {
        //do stuff 
    }

};


int main() {
    A<0> a0;
    auto a1 = A<1>();
    // auto a2 = A<2>(); //fails!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case of Ada, you can define a subtype, a new type, or a derived type that is constrained only for the values of Integer 0 and 1.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure two_value is

    -- You can use any one of the following 3 declarations. Just comment out other two.
    --subtype zero_or_one is Integer range 0 .. 1;  -- subtype of Integer.
    --type zero_or_one is range 0 .. 1;             -- new type.
    type zero_or_one is new Integer range 0 .. 1;   -- derived type from Integer.

    function get_val (val_1 : in zero_or_one) return Integer;

    function get_val (val_1 : in zero_or_one) return Integer is
    begin
        if (val_1 = 0) then
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
        end if;

    end get_val;

begin

    Put_Line("Demonstrate the use of only two values");

    Put_Line(Integer'Image(get_val(0)));
    Put_Line(Integer'Image(get_val(1)));
    Put_Line(Integer'Image(get_val(2)));

end two_value;
```

upon compiling you get the following warning message, although compiles successfully  :

```
>gnatmake two_value.adb
gcc -c two_value.adb
two_value.adb:29:40: warning: value not in range of type "zero_or_one" defined at line 8
two_value.adb:29:40: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
gnatbind -x two_value.ali
gnatlink two_value.ali
```

And executing it gives the runtime error as specified by the compiler

```
>two_value.exe
Demonstrate the use of only two values
 0
 1

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : two_value.adb:29 range check failed
```

So, basically you can constrain the values by defining the new types, derived types or subtypes, you don't need to include the code to check the range, but based on your data type the compiler will automatically warn you.

Comment: Cool! There is a rumor that Stepanov first developed the STL in Ada (The Ada Generic Library), there must be something good about this language.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to accept literal `0` that I've found to date is to use `std::nullptr_t` as the function's input:

```
struct math_object
{
    real x,y,z;
    math_object(std::nullptr_t) : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
};
```

This has conversion advantages over some of the other solutions. For example, it allows syntax such as.. `void MyFunc(const math_object &obj=0);` I've been using this for years, and haven't found any trouble. However, I do not have a similar solution for literal `1`. For that, I created a `construct::id` structure that has a global `IDENTITY` variable.

Comment: this technique used to exploit a `void*****` instead in c++98. Both have the deficiency that they only accept the literal 0 as argument but not 1.

Comment: see my answer. it accepts 1. Also it accepts 0 without this ugly trick.

Comment: I guess it depends on how dissimilar you see null vs zero. Perhaps the standard will provide a mechanism for value based overload captures at some point. Probably not anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

There's a basic problem.  How can you do that in the compiler to be done for a parameter, and at the same time be efficient?  Well, what do you need exactly?

That is included in strong typed languages like Pascal, or Ada.  The enumerated types have only a couple of values, and the types are normally checked at development, but otherwise, the checks are eliminated by some compiler option at runtime, because *just everything goes well*.

A function interface is a contract.  It is a contract between a seller (the writer of the function) and a buyer (the user of that function).  There's even an arbiter, which is the programming language, that can act upon if someone tries to cheat the contract.  But at the end, the program is being run in a machine that's open to make arbitraryness like modifying the set of enumerated values and put in the place a completely (and not permitted value).

The problem comes also with separate compilation.  Separate compilation has its drawbacks, as it must face a compilation, without having to recheck and retest all previous compilations you have made.  Once a compilation is finished, everything you have put in the code is there.  If you want the code to be efficient, then the tests are superfluous, because caller and implementer both cope with the contract, but if you want to catch a lyer, then you have to include the test code.  And then, it is better to do once for all cases, or is it better to let the programmer decide when and when not we want to catch a lyer?

The problem with C (and by legacy with C++) is that they were inspired by very good programmers, that didn't mistakes, and that have to run their software in big and slow machines.  They decided to make both languages (the second was for interoperability purposes) weak typed... and so they are.  Have you tried to program in Ada? or Modula-2?  You'll see that, over the time, the strong typing thing is more academic than otherwise, and finally what you want, as a professional, is to have the freedom to say: now I want to be safe (and include test code), and now I know what I'm doing (and please be most efficient as you can)

## Conclusion

The conclussion is that you are free to select the language, to select the compiler, and to relax the rules.  The compilers have the possibility to allow you that.  And you have to cope with it, or invent (this is something that todays happens almost each week) your own programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective, I interpret from your answer that good programmers in C (or C++) would have not bothered with this and just write a function taking an `int` and putting in the contract that the integer is either `0` or `1`. `void f_special(int zero_or_one){minimal check...}`. Yes, I guess that is a possibility, I wanted to do a little better. What annoys me  the most about this solution is implicit conversions (e.g. from double).

Comment: You can check for that yourself... and you can blame the programmer or the user in the way you want.  What you cannot do is to avoid it, if it has been hardwired in your compiler, and you don't have an option to avoid that.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your statement. What is that I cannot avoid. For your reference, IlCapitano's answer is basically the correct answer for what I was asking.

Comment: You cannot avoid the compiler including value checking if it has been included in it's design and you want to write your own value checking.

Comment: Sure, this is C++ and the check is not included in the compilation if you don't ask for it explicitly. Also, do you mean "liar"?

Comment: Programming languages that do all type checks on parameter passing tend to be heavyweight in the code they generate, mostly unused code, as the data normally comes from already ensured data.  This is 95-100% the case, and normally you have to cope with such testing in data that comes from the user.  Enumerations normally do the _neutral addition element_, _neutral multiplication element_.  But thats lazy in C++ and not done at all in C.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question, based on @IlCapitano answer for a wrapper class.
This wrapper class can be made private an used only on the construction.

```
class Matrix {
    struct ZeroOROne {
        /*implicit*/ consteval ZeroOROne(int n) : val_{n} {
            if (n != 0 and n != 1) {throw;}  // throw can produce an error at compile time
        }
        int val_;
    };

 public:
    constexpr Matrix(ZeroOROne _0_or_1) {
        if(_0_or_1.val_ == 0) {  // this cannot be if constexpr, but that is ok
            a00 = a01 = a10 = a11 = 0.0;
            new int{0};  // allocation could is ok here
        } else {
            a00 = a11 = 1.0;
            a10 = a01 = 0.0;
            new int{0};  // allocation could is ok here
        }
    }
    double a00; double a01;
    double a10; double a11;
};
```

In this way, only `Matrix A(0)` or `Matrix A(1)` are allowed.
(Although it works with constant variables as well, but that is ok.)

```
int main() {
    // ZeroOROne(0);
    // ZeroOROne(1);
    // ZeroOROne(2);  // compilation error

    Matrix A(0);
    Matrix B(1);

    // Matrix C(2);  // compilation error

    int const d = 0;  // this works because the compiler can "see" the 0.
    Matrix D(d);

    constexpr int e = 0;
    Matrix E(e);

    // int f = 0;
    // Matrix F(f);  // compile error

    return B.a00;
}
```

Here it is shown that the "runtime" `if` in the constructor is not a problem and can be elided by the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/hd6TWY6qW

The solution needs C++20 and it works in recent version of GCC and clang.

Comment: I didn't realize the algebraic types you were referring to were things like matrices. Just out of curiosity, why not just use the simpler `Matrix::zero()` and `Matrix::identity()` which reads well, and from C++17 onward would have guaranteed copy elision? IMO seeing `Matrix(1)` and `Matrix(0)` to mean identity vs zero respectively is confusing.

Comment: @Human-Compiler zero and identity are fine to have but they are not *generic* ways to generate them. for example, it will not work when “upgrading” (lifting) from a built-in to a class.

Comment: another example could be a group in which 1 is the generic identity (and 0 doesn’t exist). Again the identity for buildins is 1 not T::identity.

Comment: Sure, but a "generic way" could be done through traits or something as well; it doesn't necessarily mean everything has to be `T::identity()`. For example, `identity_traits<T>::identity()` could be implemented for builtins, like `identity_traits<int>::identity() -> int { return 1; }`. My only reason for asking is that the solution, as neat as it is, requires branches and leveraging esoteric things like an invalid constant-sub-expressions, when named functions make it easier/clearer without relying on the optimizer to remove branches.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I understand your points. I still hope that i can remove the branch but even if not everything is a hidden implementation detail which I like. And some people would say that traits are really esoteric instead. This is still an experiment anyway.

Comment: I tried a similar solution once, but had issues when overloads can accept a standard integer. It doesn't happen often, but essentially, you cannot accept an `int` anywhere where you can also accept zero or identity. It shouldn't be a problem for a matrix, though.

Comment: @Robert, I tried many things too, but this was not possible because `consteval` I think. Do you see any problem with *this* solution?